# Jquery does not empty partial view after second execution of onclick modal dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

## Facts

- I have an mvc project.
- I am using jquery.

## The problem

$('#ModalData').empty(); is not working as I expected.

## Details

When I click on the test link three times I get
[image]

However, the hello world was supposed to be emptied by
$('#ModalData').empty();
but it doesnt. Instead everytime I click on test link it open the modal dialog and creates a new hello world.

Also note that If I append the html without using partial view then jquery empty works. Any help?

```
 $(".modal").on("click", function () {

        $.ajaxSetup({

        cache: false
    });
    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");

    $('#ModalData').empty();//not working to well

    $.get("/MedicineManagement/GetModal/", function (data)
    { $("#ModalAjaxData").append(data); });
});


$("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 400,
    width: 550,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Modify Actual Potential": function () {


            if (true) {
                $(this).dialog("close");

            }
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");

        }
    },
    close: function () {


    }
});
```

## Controller

```
     [HttpGet]
        public PartialViewResult GetModal()
        {
            return PartialView("_AddMedicineList");
        }
```

## HTML that triggers jquery

```
 <div id="dialog-form" title="Edit Actual Potential">
        <div class="ModalAjaxData" id="ModalAjaxData"></div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class ="modal">test </a>
```

Comment: Typo? $('#ModalData').empty() should be $('#ModalAjaxData').empty() ?

Comment: yes typo also . i think both of u helped a lot thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your AJAX success callback you are appending:

```
$("#ModalAjaxData").append(data);
```

instead of setting the html of the `#ModalAjaxData` div:

```
$("#ModalAjaxData").html(data);
```

Also you seem to be emptying some `#ModalData` element which I cannot see anywhere in your markup so it is not surprising that `$('#ModalData').empty();` does nothing. You probably meant `$('#ModalAjaxData').empty();`. But if you use `$("#ModalAjaxData").html(data);` instead of appending you don't need to be emptying anything.

Comment: incredeble i am going  to see what is the difference between append and .html

Comment: The difference is that `.append()` (as it name suggests) appends to the DOM, whereas `.html()` replaces the contents of the element.